# Can view another Exchange 2010 user's mailbox items via OWA, but not Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, permissions, exchange, exchange-2010

I need to make some mailboxes available to more than one user.

As a test, I've added myself to another users mailbox's permission list using the management shell:

```
add-mailboxpermission -Identity 'shared@example.com' -User 'me@exmaple.com' -AccessRights FullAccess
```

The mailbox then automatically shows up in my folder list because it is automapping. I can browse the full hierarchy, but contents are not visible.

When I connect to OWA, I can connect to the other mailbox as my user, and view it as if I were logged in as them.

If I add myself via Outlooks GUI ( I can modify permissions etc... ) as a "Owner", then I am able to see the contents of that particular folder. Because the permissions do not cascade from the mailbox down to the the base folders/sub folders, I'm not particularly interested in this option.

I need to apply this to several mailboxes for several different users, with an unknown number of sub folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a caching issue. Outlook behaved correctly after switching profile from cached to non-cached.